# Setting Up ASP.NET Identity Core in an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to start a new web application project and I wanted to use the asp.net identity database (the one with all the AspNet tables (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles etc)).

I have tried to follow numerous guides, these among other:

- bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/
- johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/
- tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-identity-tutorial-basics/%20%22ASP.Net%20Identity%20Tutoria
- benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

However when I tried to create the database I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD1VW.png).

I have also tried to do it by mimicking the template project (ASP.NET Core Web Application(.Net Core)) in Visual Studio with the same result or [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YEUc.png)

This is how my project looks like, its basically the template minus the Controllers, Views and Models.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //var connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

        //services.AddEntityFramework()
        //    .AddSqlServer()
        //    .AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(o =>
        //    o.UseSqlServer(connString));

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

I just want to have an empty project with asp.net identity, preferably in SQL server instead of in localdb. Does anyone have a easy guide or know why it does not work for me?

EDIT1

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext() : this("Data Source=ACLAP;Initial Catalog=tmpCore;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False") { }
}
```

EDIT2
I have put up the project on github.

github.com/KiBlob/test

Comment: I do not think there is anything wrong with your code.  Something seems odd with your Visual Studio.  That is the command to push the Migration Update to the DB.  When you type in the Package Manager Console, you should get a drop-down of options.  Also, it might be worth noting that it is 'kind of' capsensative, so I would try Update-Database

Comment: When I do "Add-Migration InitialCreate" or "Update-Database" I get this error message

"System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString"

But I have basically copied the part it complains on from the VS template.

Comment: Do you have a connection string in your Web Config?

Comment: @JasonH No, but neither does the VS template I have copied from.  
Even with the connection string in web config i get the same error.

Comment: Try changing your DBContext Constructor to this:
  public ApplicationDbContext()
   : this("myConnectionString")
  {
  }

Comment: @JasonH You mean like this (check EDIT1 in original post). I get error, complaining that ApplicationDbContext does not contain constructor that takes 1 argument.

Comment: OK that is weird, one of the constructors is ctor(string nameOrConnectionString)

Comment: @JasonH If you have time and could look up the project at https://github.com/KiBlob/test it would be really nice. I have probably missed something really obvious. I only want an empty project with asp.net identity and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: OK I just realized, you are NOT using Identity 2.0 (or 2.2 which is the current version).  You are trying to use the new 'Core' Frameworks...so ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core, Identity Core, etc.  None of this is official and still has many bugs.  I personally have not use any of it yet because they (Microsoft) keeps changing things in it.  Just as I learn about something new, they take it away.  If you are trying to learn EF and Identity, I recommend going back to EF 6 and Identity 2.2.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.2.1

Comment: @JasonH I didnt realize that it was called identity core and not 2.2. I have been using asp.net 5 (which is now called asp.net core i believe) and EF7 and I was hoping  could continue doing that. Do you think there is anything I can do to make that project work. Setting up an ASP.NET Identity Core in an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application project?

Comment: Sadly as I stated, I have not played with Core much.  I did a bit last year but then they started making some major changes and found that things I hard learned were removed from the RC so I decided to just wait until it goes RTM (Final).  I believe the tentative date is late June but that may change as they are having some issues still.

Comment: @JasonH No problem, thank you very much for the help. I found another guide that I am going to give a try at pluralsight https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-core-1-0-fundamentals.

Comment: Try `dnx ef database update` instead of `update-database` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, do you have defined the DefaultConnection in your appsettings.json file?

Mine looks like this:

```html
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=[SERVER];Database=[DB];Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Try setting the connection there and then run Update-Database again.

Note: If you have multiple projects in your solution, make sure that the Default project in the package manager console is pointing to the project where the connection is set before running Update-Database.

Comment: I see the structure Data->DefaultConnection->ConnectionString everywhere.  This answer shows the appsettings.json format that actually allowed me to pull the connection string from Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") in DNX 1.0.